Why did Yitzchok give perhaps the worst answer to eisavs question
When Eisav asks Yakov Avinu where did my Bracha go, Yitzchok answers him and says your brother Yackov came to me cunningly and stole your bracha. There were a lot of much better answers Yitzchok could have answered Eisav. Why did Yitzchok give the worst answer possible causing eisav to become enraged and to want to kill Yackov?? Other better answers Yitzchok could have given perhaps could have been: "Someone else came here and forced me to bless them", or "A divine nevuah told me I can't bless you, I'm sorry". Anything but not the answer of "your brother came here cunningly and took your Bracha!"

What better answer would you have preferred?

In theory he could have said nothing at all and just blessed Esav. But he was pretty shaken up.

Saying "the worst" - is an opinion. Could you change the language? Does the answer need justifying that it's "the worst"? Thank you.

Because it was, um...... The truth?

There was no nevua, saying so is very bad. Yitzchak instead could speak to Eisav about why he wanted to give him a blessing. That is a good question.
